# I want to print a tabloid report using 4 pages as sub-reports

Tags: ms-access, report

I want to print a tabloid report, front and back, and I need to use page backgrounds which work as individual pages.

How can I print 4 letter size reports on 11*17 paper?

I did try to do this as sub-reports but the output printed frames with no content

Comment: What do you mean by 'page backgrounds"? This appears to be a design not coding issue and therefore is not appropriate for SO.